# Electrical safety of wires in furniture

Tags: electrical

I have a sofa that has 2 reclining motors in either side. When I opened it up the power cable is split, it connects to the right motor and then is wired all along the bottom of the frame  with zip ties to the left motor. The back leather material flap of the back of the sofa actually touches these wires.

Now the power supply is only 29volts but something about material touching power wires makes me uneasy. Although from what I can tell this is standard practice. Is this not a safety issue? What if a wired broke, would there be a serious fire hazard?

Comment: That's why wires are insulated

Comment: Do you take the wiring apart in your car? There are similar motors for windows and mirrors that get flexed every time you open the door just saying…

Answer (score 1):

If the furniture is UL listed (or similar) then design review and testing should have considered these issues. That being said, things can go wrong over time on even the best designed and built equipment.

Arc Fault Circuit Interrupters (AFCI) can help a lot, as they can often detect the arcing of damaged wires, preventing a fire.

Comment: If the furniture is powered only by low voltage that is fed from a transformer (wallwart, or other similar in-line transformer), would the furniture itself need to be UL listed, or only the transformer itself?  It was my understanding that only line-level equipment falls under the UL listings, and this is why many pieces of equipment have gone to separate transformers that plug into the devices, so the devices themselves don't need to be UL listed/tested.

Comment: My general understanding is that (a) products that are not themselves directly mains powered *can* get UL listing, but that UL listing is much easier than for mains powered devices, assuming the wall wart is itself *already* UL listed; (b) from an NEC standpoint, the part that matters is the wall wart (or similar).